# Ruby float number (currency) to words

Tags: ruby

Is there any gem for converting currency strings like: "$1.01" to "One dollar one cent"?

I have found [number_and_words](https://github.com/kslazarev/numbers_and_words) gem, but it doesn't have option for converting floats as currency. It converts "1.01" as "one and one hundredth" which is completely unrelated to currency

Answer (score 2):

I am personally unaware of such a gem, but using the gem you did find, could easily make a method to achieve it.

Split the string on the dot, and then convert each side (I don't know the actual method name):

```
parts = '1.01'.split('.')
words = "#{convert(part[0])} dollars and #{convert(parts[1])} cents"
```

It would be far easier than trying to find a gem with such a specific feature, when it only takes a line or two of code to achieve with what you already have.

Depending on how good you want the grammar to be, you may also want to check that the values are greater than 1 so you know whether to use "dollar" or "dollars" and "cent" or "cents".